# Meaning of $(stat -c%s file.name

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to convert a bash script to Python that displays the progress of a file being written. The bash script has

```
build_size=$(stat -c%s file.name)
```

Which in the bash script makes a variable of the completion percent of the file. I'm curious about what the

```
stat -c%s
```

is doing, so that I can do the same operation in a Python script.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `man 1 stat` will tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man stat`:

> -c  --format=FORMAT
> use  the specified FORMAT instead of the default; output a newline after each use of FORMAT

And:

> %s     total size, in bytes

So it gives the size in bytes. Also, the name `build_size` kind of gives it away :-)